# Replace semicolons separated values with another table values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Books` and `Authors`.

Table `Books`

```
ID     Title     Authors
1      apple     1;2;3;
2      cancer    1;5;
```

Table `Authors`

```
ID     Name
1      John
2      Mike
3      Joe
4      Katy
5      Sara
```

I need a query which result is

```
ID     Title     Authors
1      apple     John;Mike;Joe
2      cancer    John;Sara
```

Comment: Just for correction, those are not comma, they are called **semicolon**

Comment: @RahulTripathi you are write, just a flub! ;)

Comment: UPDATE YourTable
SET Authors = REPLACE(Authors, ';', ';')

SQL Server Helper
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? But you must ensure that Authors column in Books table always has valid data.

```
SELECT ID,
       Title,
       STUFF(CAST((SELECT ';' + aut.Name 
                     FROM Authors aut 
                    WHERE aut.ID IN 
                       (SELECT CAST(Split.a.value('.','VARCHAR(max)') AS int) As bid  
                          FROM  
                             ( SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(LEFT(Authors, DATALENGTH(Authors)-1), ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                             ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS    Split(a))  
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE))AS nvarchar(max)), 1,1,'')
 FROM Books
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is split the strings first into separate rows then join that to the other table, and then parse it back together to the same structure.

For splitting the string I'd recommend using DelimitedSplit8k by Jeff Moden (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), and the final thing should look something like this (can't test this now, but hopefully it's ok):

```
select b.id, b.title, d.Item as c 
into #tmp 
from books b cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(b.authors, ';') as d

select t2.id, t2.title, (SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT ';' + a.name 
              FROM #tmp t1
              join authors a on a.id = t1.c
              where t1.id = t2.id
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')) as Name
from (
  select distinct id, title from #tmp
) t2
```

Comment: it works for 1-author books, but not for multi authors. by the way thanks for your time

Comment: It should work, but since I couldn't test it, most likely there's a bug or two somewhere :). #tmp should contain one row per author, each of the authors being in the c -column, and the select should parse it back together.

Comment: There was a comma instead of semicolon in the select clause when parsing the data back together, but can't see anything else wrong with it.